# Is there an order of priority for washing Mayim Achronim

Tags: halacha, food, orach-chaim, honors, mayim-acharonim

In Halacha, is there an order of priority for who gets to wash Mayim Achronim first or last? So say multiple people are eating together, and one is a kohen or Levi or Talmid chacham or your parent, etc. do you have to let them wash first? What if you finish eating before them, do you have to wait for them or no?

Comment: OC 181:6 https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%A4%D7%90_%D7%95

Comment: According to the Gemara in Berachos (I don't recall the exact daf, help me out here please!) it's an insult to tell someone to wash mayim achronim, because it's as if you're admonishing him for eating too much, or you're saying that his hands are filthy.